# Skype screen sharing

Tags: skype

With [skype premium](http://www.skype.com/en/premium/) there is a possibility to share screens among a group of people. But what I wonder is if 
*a free account can let **one** person share her screen to all others*. The web site does not specify exaclty what configurations are allowed in free vs premium

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this won't exactly answer your question, but if you don't use this function on a very frequent basis, [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/fr/Index.aspx) could do this for free and share screens both ways (without even installing the software, you can just run it once from the installer). It's not skype though. Hope this won't get me a downvote.

Comment: what way is the most smooth one?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: best experience, skype or teamviewer?

Comment: I barely know teamviewer as i've only done one job interview on it, but it seems to have a better image quality and fluidity than skype over poor networks. I'd advise to go with teamviewer, mostly because i know it can do what you want for free, and i'm not sure if skype can.

Answer (score 0):

Finding anything on Skype's website is not an easy task. I had premium account for one year, so based on my experience, here is what I know:

**Free**

1. Voice Chat: 4 parties
2. Video Chat: 2 parties
3. Screen Sharing: only one party

**Premium**

1. Voice Chat: 12-15 parties
2. Video Chat: 3 parties
3. Screen Sharing: did not try

Please note that I have tried these numbers, I am not sure about the maximum limit.